# Excel DSum (possibly another way)

Tags: excel, aggregate-functions

I have a costing spreadsheet for personal use. Each cost is categorised by a value selected from a 'Categories' list. So far so good.

I want to make a summary which shows total costs for each category. I was thinking of using DSum but cannot get it to work.

Let me explain better: consider the below example

Main List:

```
Date    Category          Cost
----    --------          ----
01/Jul  Book              20.00
03/Jul  Stationery         2.00
05/Jul  Book              15.00
```

Summary:

```
Category          Cost
--------          ----
Book              35.00
Stationery         2.00
```

Any help or pointers to a solution appreciated on how to do summary.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using a pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pivot table would be the easiest. Select the source data, then click Insert > Pivot table. Drag the category to the Rows field well and the Cost to the Values field well and ensure that calculation is set to sum, not count.

If you want to do it with formulas, you will need to manually generate a list of categories, for example starting with "Book" in A2 on the Summary sheet. Then you can use a Sumif function like this:

```
=Sumif('MainList'!$B:$B,B2,'Main List'!$C:$C)
```

In words: return the sum of all cells in Main List column C where Main List column B matches the text in cell B2 on this sheet.

Comment: I did try the pivot table but it was not recalculating when the main dataset was updated.

SumIf did the trick perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: I did mark it but was notified that my marks will not count as I have less than 15 reputation marks on this site.